# mysql insert from generated names

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="aaa" id="aaa">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have also jQuery script and can append this input.

Example:

Generating name.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="aaa" >
<input type="text" name="aaa2" >
<input type="text" name="aaa3" >

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Problems is MySQL insert:

How to insert from generated names?

I know `$_POST['aaa']`, but I don't know from generated names.

Comment: Loop through `$_POST`  `foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { // do stuff }`

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating dynamically text boxes from jQuery and you want to push them to mySQL, instead of creating them with names like 'aaa', 'aaa2' or 'aaa3' you can use square brackets like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="field_name[]">
    <input type="text" name="field_name[]">
    <input type="text" name="field_name[]">
    <input type="text" name="field_name[]">
    <input type="text" name="field_name[]">
    <input type="text" name="field_name[]">
    <input type="text" name="field_name[]">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

That will allow you to use "field_name" as an array of strings.

```
<?php
    $field_name = $_REQUEST['field_name'];
    foreach($field_name as $value) {
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO table SET field_name = '%s'", $value);
        /* Execute Insert Query */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. if i have form like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="aaa">
    <input type="text" name="bbb">
    <input type="text" name="ccc">
```

and i apend 3 input's

```
    <input type="text" name="aaa">
    <input type="text" name="bbb">
    <input type="text" name="ccc">

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

in mysql i have table:

id
aaa
bbb
ccc

this is one insert